# SQL To Aggregate by Category Membership

Tags: sql

I've been kluding around with this and thought someone might have a clever way to solve my problem.  I'm querying sales by category membership and need to aggregate ALL sales if a customer is a member of a single sales category.  For example:

```
Cust  Category   Sale
 A      Pie        3
 A      Cake       5
 B      Pie        4
 C      Cake       8
 C      Limes      1
```

In the example, I want to get the total sales for any one with a category = 'Cake', resulting in:

```
Cust   Sale
 A       8
 C       9
```

I've been writing two queries (or subquerying) but wondered if there was a direct approach that I was missing.  Of course the real data is more complex but this is the gist of what I want to accomplish.  Any thoughts on how to do this efficiently without subquerying?

Comment: What database system you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the EXISTS operator with correlated subquery in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT t1.Cust, SUM(t1.Sale) AS Sale
FROM dbo.test134 t1
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.test134 t2
              WHERE t1.Cust = t2.Cust
                AND t2.Category = 'Cake'
              )
GROUP BY t1.Cust
```

Or aggregate function with OVER clause for SQLServer2005+

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT Cust, Category, SUM(Sale) OVER(PARTITION BY Cust) AS Sale
  FROM dbo.test134
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM cte
  WHERE Category = 'Cake'
```

See a demo of both queries [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78f62/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A.Cust, A.Category, B.SumSale
from Sales A
Where A.Category like '%Cake%'
Left Join
(Select Cust, Category, Sum(Sale) as SumSale
from Sales 
Group By Cust, Category) B
On B.Cust = A.Cust
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible with CTE:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT Cust FROM demo
  WHERE Category = 'Cake'
)
SELECT cte.Cust, SUM(Sale) AS Sales FROM demo
JOIN cte ON cte.Cust = demo.Cust
GROUP BY cte.Cust
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
SELECT Category, Sum(Sales) AS [Sale Totals]
FROM tblSales
GROUP BY Category
```

EDIT:  This is for if you want to group by all categories, not just 'Cake'.
EDIT 2:  However, if you only want a single category, just add a simple:

```
WHERE Category = 'Cake'
```

in between the FROM and the GROUP BY lines.

Comment: -1: No, that rejects non-matching rows from the `SUM`. The OP only wishes to reject non-matching _people_.